# Tengo una duda en mi programa, no llego a entender mucho como funcionan los metodos y objetos

Tags: java

Les paso la clase donde están mis métodos, ahí señalo donde me dice error:

```
private float arreglo[];

public ArregloFloat(int nroElementos){
    this.arreglo = null;
    this.arreglo = new float[nroElementos];
}

public ArregloFloat(float arregloAux[]){

    for(int i = 0; i < arregloAux.length; i++){
        this.arreglo[i] = arregloAux[i];        //aquí me aparece el error
    }
}
```

en el main creo el  objeto:
ArregloFloat obj = new ArregloFloat(m); // m es un arreglo que creo

Además en todo el programa no utilizo el primer constructor, pero me piden que lo cree, ayuda por favor, no sé si algo he hecho mal...

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. ¿Podrías poner el error que aparece?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at arregloFloat.ArregloFloat.<init>(ArregloFloat.java:29)
 at arregloFloat.ArregloFloatTest1.main(ArregloFloatTest1.java:23)
C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: justo la linea 29 es donde señalo y la 23 es en el main, en la creacion del objeto

Comment: No puedo saber las líneas de tu código sólo con la pregunta que has hecho. Pero creo que se el motivo de tu error. Te escribo la respuesta.

Comment: Okey, espero entonces, gracias de todas formas!

Comment: Cuando llamas el constructor `ArregloFloat(float arregloAux[])` *arreglo* es null. Nada mas. Debes incializarlo como en el otro constructor. Algo asÍ - `this.arreglo = new float[arregloAux.length];`

Answer (score 0):

Tu clase ArregloFloat tiene 2 constructores, pero para el uso que quieres darle solo necesitas el primer constructor:

```
public ArregloFloat(int nroElementos){
    this.arreglo = null;
    this.arreglo = new float[nroElementos];
}
```

Este constructor crea un array de `float` con el tamaño que le indiques en la variable`m` aquí `ArregloFloat obj = new ArregloFloat(m);`

Al intentar crear un objeto `ArregloFloat` con un array `float` `m` te da error porque la variable privada `private float arreglo[];` no esta iniciada y haces uso de ella.

Puedes tener n constructores siempre que tengan diferentes párametros/argumentos. En el caso anterior, al crear tu objeto con el constructor con parámetro `array`, no te está inicializando el array privado de la clase.

Para que funcione, primero debemos saber lo que quieres hacer con está clase. Una posible solución es cambiar el segundo constructor por un método:

```
public void ArregloFloatRecorrer(float arregloAux[]) {
   for (int i = 0; i < arregloAux.length; i++) {
      this.arreglo[i] = arregloAux[i]; // aquí me aparece el error
   }
}
```

Y al construir tu objeto ArregloFloat hacer algo similar a esto:

```
ArregloFloat obj = new ArregloFloat(10);
float arr1[] = new float[] {1f, 2f, 3f, 5f, 9f};
obj.ArregloFloatRecorrer(obj);
```

De este modo estas creando un objeto ArregloFloat, en el que `private float arreglo[];` se crea con una dimensión `10`. Luego se crea un nuevo array `arr1` y el array `arreglo` toma los valores de `arr1`.